# Проблема с кодировкой в базе данных

Tags: python, база-данных, кодировка, перекодировка, sql

Мне удалось подключиться к базе данных Борей (Access) и скопировать из нее часть информации в созданную идентичную базу данных на Firebird. Вот код делающий это:

```
conAcc = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=D:\ThirdTask\Northwind.accdb')
SqlAccess=conAcc.cursor();
SqlAccess.execute(sql.sql_count_records_clients);
CountOfRecords=SqlAccess.fetchone()[0];
print CountOfRecords
id=0
conn.begin()
cur=conn.cursor()
while id<CountOfRecords:
    id+=1
    SqlAccess.execute(sql.sql_allfields_clients, (id,))
    clientdict=dict(ident=id, organization=SqlAccess.fetchone()[1]);
    print clientdict
    s=''
    s="INSERT INTO CLIENTS (ID, COMPANY) VALUES"
    s+="("+str(clientdict['ident'])+", " +"\'"+clientdict['organization']+"\'"+")"
    print s
    cur.execute(s)
conn.commit()    
conn.close()
conAcc.close();
```

Привожу модуль sql.py

```
# -*- coding: cp1251 -*-
sqltables='''SELECT id, name, description, can_add, can_edit, can_delete FROM tables'''
sqlfields = '''SELECT fields.position,fields.name,fields.description,
data_types.type_id,domains.char_length,
fields.can_input,fields.can_edit,
fields.show_in_grid,fields.is_mean, fields.autocalculated,
fields.required
FROM fields
JOIN domains ON fields.domain_id = domains.id
JOIN data_types ON domains.data_type_id = data_types.id
WHERE fields.table_id = ?
ORDER BY fields.position
'''
sqlconstraints='''SELECT constraints.id,
constraints.name, constraint_type, constraints.reference,
tables.name
FROM constraints
LEFT JOIN tables ON constraints.table_id = tables.id
WHERE table_id = ? '''
sql_constr_det = '''SELECT fields.name, tables.name
FROM constraint_details
JOIN fields ON constraint_details.field_id = fields.id
JOIN tables ON tables.id=fields.table_id
WHERE constraint_id = ?
AND tables.id= ? '''
sqlindices = '''SELECT indices.id,indices.name
FROM indices
WHERE indices.table_id = ? '''
sql_indices_fields = '''SELECT fields.name,
index_details.position
FROM indices
JOIN index_details ON index_id = indices.id
JOIN fields ON field_id = fields.id
WHERE indices.table_id = ?
AND indices.id=?'''
sql_indices_descend='''SELECT index_details.descend
FROM index_details
JOIN indices ON index_details.index_id = indices.id
JOIN fields ON field_id = fields.id 
WHERE indices.table_id = ?
AND indices.id = ?
AND fields.name = ?'''
sql_fields='''SELECT fields.name
FROM fields
JOIN tables ON tables.id=fields.table_id
JOIN constraints ON (constraints.table_id=tables.id and constraints.constraint_type='PRIMARY')
JOIn constraint_details ON (constraint_details.constraint_id=constraints.id and constraint_details.field_id=fields.id)
WHERE tables.name= ?'''
sql_count_records_clients='''SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Customers'''
sql_allfields_clients='''SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE ИД=?'''
```

Но в результате вставки в поле COMPANY таблицы CLIENTS информация представляется не в кириллице. Как изменить кодировку clientdict['organization'], чтоб информация отображалась правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы посмотрел в сторону COLLATE.

Comment: @msi что такое COLLATE и можно подробнее - что предлагаете сделать?

Comment: Установите кириллическую коллацию для соответствующего столбца.
Читайте документацию, я с FB не работаю.